# Python sort strings alphabetically, lowercase first

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort a given array of strings alphabetically using python, but lowercase words should appear first.

An example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
arr=['A','e','a','D','f','B']
arr.sort()
for s in arr: print s
```

Input:

```
A
e
a
D
f
B
```

Output (current):

```
A
B
D
a
e
f
```

Output (should be):

```
a
e
f
A
B
D
```

Comment: Note that all answers so far sort _letters_ (as in your example), not _words_ (as in your question).

Comment: Actually, mine does sort words, I just didn't show it in my example.

Comment: @georg Wrong. They all do sort words. Sort on first character, then second character etc, up until a whole word. The only matter here is that the standard sort has a different sort index than what the OP wants. `string.ascii_letters` has this order. Any solution that creates something in between is obsolete.

Comment: @PascalvKooten: test example: sorting `['Abc', 'abc', 'aBc']` should return `['abc', 'aBc', 'Abc']`

Comment: @georg I now see what you mean, this indeed completely changes everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a custom key method which checks whether the item is not `.lower()` and then compares the items itself. For `'A'`, `'D'` and `'B'` `not x.islower()` will return `True` and for other it is `False`, as `True > False` smaller case items will come first:

```
>>> arr = ['A','e','a','D','f','B']
>>> arr.sort(key=lambda x:(not x.islower(), x))
>>> arr
['a', 'e', 'f', 'A', 'B', 'D']
```

Comment: Strangely it returns `None` on me

Comment: @howaboutNO Don't assign return value of `arr.sort` to a variable, it sorts the list in-place.

Comment: I think it worthy to mention that `False < True` is true in python. That's why `(False, 'f') < (True, 'A') `

Comment: Good solution not using an import.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Missed that. My bad. Elegant solution, by tha way.

Comment: Even though this answer sorts multiple words wrongly (e.g. `['a','P','v Q']`  results in `['a','P','v Q']`, instead of `['a','v Q','P']`, I did not ask for that and this answer fits more to my needs :).

Answer (score 11):

To sort words, and not simply letters, just swap the case:

```
>>> words = ['alpha', 'Alpha', 'aLpha', 'Bravo', 'bRavo']
>>> sorted(words)
['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'aLpha', 'alpha', 'bRavo']
>>> sorted(words, key=str.swapcase)
['alpha', 'aLpha', 'bRavo', 'Alpha', 'Bravo']
```

Comment: I stand corrected: this should indeed be the best answer (it is the only correct one). It's also very concise. Well done (will change upvote when possible).

Comment: This is the same answer as the second part of Tanveer`s answer and is correct and even sorts correctly multiple words. Upvote.

Answer (score 3):

We can use [`string.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) to get index of each letters to sort them.

```
arr = ['A','e','a','D','f','B']

import string

print sorted(arr, key=string.ascii_letters.index)
```

Results:

```
['a', 'e', 'f', 'A', 'B', 'D']
```

Or if you want to sort the original `arr` list use [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) built-in function.

```
arr.sort(key=string.ascii_letters.index)
print arr
```

---

If the `arr` list is having words instead of single letters or alphabets we can use [`str.swapcase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase)

```
arr = ['Abc', 'abc', 'aBc']
print sorted(arr, key=str.swapcase)
```

Yields:

```
['abc', 'aBc', 'Abc']
```

Comment: @PascalvKooten Thanks for the appreciation.

Comment: The lambda call is redundant, `.index` is already a callable: `arr.sort(key=string.ascii_letters.index)`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks a lot. Initially  I was trying to sort it by `ord` and `lambda` so didn't focus on that.

Comment: Only issue is indeed that it does not sort words. E.g. `sorted(['Abc', 'abc', 'aBc'], key = lambda x: [string.ascii_letters.index(y) for y in x])`

Comment: @PascalvKooten Yes in case of words we can sort them based on the first letter. I have included in my answer please check, Thanks

Comment: @TanveerAlam That would still break when the tie-breaker is in later than the 2nd character.

Comment: @PascalvKooten Thats true. I think in that case `str.swapcase` mentioned by `georg` would be most efficient.

Comment: Very nice detailed answer, upvote. The accepted answer fits my needs more, though this answer is better when sorting multiple words.

Answer (score 2):

Some timings show that for sorting single characters creating a dict is the actually most efficient:

python2.7:

```
from string import ascii_letters

d = {b:a for a, b  in enumerate(ascii_letters)}

In [34]: timeit  sorted(s, key=str.swapcase)
10 loops, best of 3: 32.6 ms per loop

In [35]: timeit sorted(s,key=lambda x: (not x.islower(),x))
10 loops, best of 3: 51.4 ms per loop

In [37]: timeit (sorted(s ,key=d.get))
10 loops, best of 3: 22.4 ms per loop
```

Python3.4:

```
In [4]: timeit sorted(s,key=lambda x: (not x.islower(),x))
10 loops, best of 3: 57.7 ms per loop

In [5]: timeit  sorted(s, key=str.swapcase)
10 loops, best of 3: 41.2 ms per loop

In [6]: timeit (sorted(s ,key=d.get))
10 loops, best of 3: 21.1 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Given : Alphanumeric string

Aim: To sort by rules

1. Small letters first.
2. Then capital letters.
3. Then digits (even first, odd last) (Least priority).

   ```
   def func(l):
       if l.islower():
           return ord(l) - 32
       elif l.isupper():
           return ord(l) + 32
       elif l.isdigit():
           if int(l) % 2 == 0:
               return ord(l) + 200
           else:
               return ord(l) + 100

   print(*sorted(st, key=func), sep='')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3.9

#### Sort inplace

```
arr=['A','e','a','D','f','B']
arr.sort(key=lambda x: (x.isupper(), x))
arr
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'e', 'f', 'A', 'B', 'D']
```

**Note - while using sort method**

Exceptions are not suppressed - if any comparison operations fail, the entire sort operation will fail (and the list will likely be left in a partially modified state).

#### Sort and assign to another variable keeping the original list intact

```
arr=['A','e','a','D','f','B']
sorted_arr = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: (x.isupper(), x))
sorted_arr
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'e', 'f', 'A', 'B', 'D']
```